# DRF:Updating particular fields in database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created an api to create users. But now I require to update their information based on their `id`.(I want to create a new api for this task).

So I wrote the following:

**views.py**

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.branch = request.data.get("branch")
        instance.year = request.data.get("year")
        instance.save()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

In my model I have fields as `username`, `email`, `branch`, `year`, `full name`. If at time of registration user fills few fields and after some time he gets to fill other fields(branch, year). How do I make it possible

Comment: Use `ProfileSerializer.Meta.fields`. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

Comment: Make sure that the Account model fields that are not required have default values or `null=True`, so that the model can be saved with the initial data only.

Answer (score 0):

serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):        
        instance.branch = validated_data.get('branch', instance.branch)
        instance.year = validated_data.get('year', instance.year)        
        instance.save()        
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
    api_view = ['PUT']

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.DATA
        user_details = Account.objects.get(id=request.query_params.get("id"))   
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(user_details, data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():            
            serializer.save()           
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:            
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user_details/', views.ProfileView),
)
```

Access your PUT using this path: /api/userdetails/?id=1

Now, update user information(branch, year) based on their id.